# Converting text data to table/csv format

Tags: r, csv, export-to-csv, csvtotable

I need to convert text data (e.g., paragraph) into a dataframe (to save as a csv file) using R.

The following code converts the text into a table, but it puts words in each line in a single cell.

```
    merchant <- read.delim("merchant.txt")
    write.table(merchant,file="merchant.csv",sep=",",col.names=FALSE,row.names=FALSE)
```

How can I split the words in each paragraph (line), and thus create a single-column dataset with each word in a separate cell?

Comment: try: read.delim("merchant.txt", sep = '  ') . Could you provide an example of file you want to parse?

Comment: Hi Pawel, it is giving me this error message "Error in read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  : 
  more columns than column names"

Comment: show me part of merchant.txt please

Comment: Pawel, thanks for helping with this. I'm trying to convert this script into data (http://shakespeare.mit.edu/merchant/full.html)
I tried the following as you suggested, it reads the file and converts into a table. Somehow the write.csv command doesn't seem to work.    
     data <- read.delim("merchant.txt", sep = ' ', header = FALSE)
data1 <- write.table(data, sep=",",col.names=FALSE,row.names=FALSE)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my attempt based on tidyverse. Instead of reading in as a table, just read in as a string and then separate into a vector of individual words:

```
library(tidyverse)

## Read in text file as string
merchant <- read_file("merchant.txt") %>% 
## Remove all punctuation
gsub('[[:punct:] ]+',' ',.) %>%
## Split individual words into list vector
strsplit(" ")
## Set column equal to the vector of individual words
para <- merchant[[1]]
```

To convert this into a dataframe:

```
para <- as.data.frame(para)
```

Comment: Hi Tom, that solves the problem. Thanks very much indeed.

Comment: Hi Tom, it does work, but it seems to remove the first word in each paragraph. And advise?

Comment: It doesn't seem to omit the first word of a single paragraph .txt file when I test it. Could you share the start of your .txt file? 

If you have multiple paragraphs in the file, you will need to modify the code to split the string by a regex for each paragraph, then iterate over each separate para using the code provided.

Comment: Hi Tom, thank very much. It has multiple paragraphs. I'll follow your advise. Thanks very much.